# How do I construct a safe sleeping area in 1.5 version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since 1.5 old rules for safe sleeping are no longer working. What are the new rules?

With the addition of weather, sleeping in bed is much more important and old rules for safe placements of beds no longer work (mob always spawns when sleeping is attempted).

I can't find any information about the new rules.

Comment: Uh, what exactly changed? I just used a bed that was in a safe spot (lit building), and nothing spawned on me. (The bed was at least 5 blocks from any external wall, also).

Comment: @Cyclops Well, before 1.5 it was just 1 block from any wall. I will try 5.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Mine's touching a wall, just flipped and I can sleep fine. I don't see anything on the wiki's [version history page](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Version_history) that mentions bed changes either. Maybe it has something to do with transparent materials or steps near your bed that are now acting as solid objects?

Comment: Uh-oh, stair blocks are no longer transparent? So they can spawn mobs? That could explain a few... surprises I got on the way to test beds...

Comment: People are reporting a bug that might have something to do with doors (wolves can now enter doors so this has led it to be the biggest culprit).  I have never had a problem with my bed in 1.5 though, so I think its more of luck and wait for the fix for the bug.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - The rule of thumb I always saw was 'there must be at least a two block buffer in all directions where mobs can't spawn', ie if it's next to a wall, the wall has to be two blocks thick, otherwise it needs to be at least a block from any 1-thick wall.  (I haven't upgraded yet so I can't claim to have tested this; too busy playing Portal 2.)

Comment: Well, once, i had a world where was everything inv edited, but i couldnt skip the night...
After that, i raged ( xD ) and i have put my bed in middle of the room which was like 20x20x20 cube with giant hole in it...and put torches on literaly every block...exept 1 door i had in there, i tried to sleep, but skeleton waited me next to my head...
so i was thinking, and i have surounded my bed with 1 tick wooden planks blocks...with 1 torch inside, and i sleept, it worked....without door, in room small just enough when i wake up, i dont be in seiling, but on the bed...i woke up on the bed as i sai

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After extensive testing I have found out that the problem is with the level on which the door is in relation to the surrounding. Each door needs to have at least 4 blocks in each direction on the same level as the door itself.

```
0000000000000
001111XXXXXX0
001111X1111X0
001111X1BB1X0
001111D1111X0
001111X1111X0
001111X1111X0
001111X1111X0
001111XXXXXX0
0000000000000
```

`0`,`1` - ground levels, `X` - wall, `B` - bed, `D` - door

[image]

Comment: Seriously? Man...this is going to require some renovations to my tunnel entrance.

Comment: @Robert New tests show that it is indeed the doors, but the problem seems to be elsewhere. This doesn't help always. Still testing.

Comment: Adding more flat space behind my doors did keep me safe for one night. Thanks for your testing. I'm going to provide a link to this on the GetSatisfaction bug page.

Answer (score 2):

I dug myself a tunnel into a huge rock formation, cleared out a small 3x3 room, lit it, and put down my bed, and was able to successfully sleep there.  It looked like so:

```
#########
### . ###
D.  BB###
### . ###
#########
```

`#`= Wall, `D`=Door, `.`=Torch, `B`=Bed

The tunnel/doorway are 2 blocks high, and the 3x3 "room" is also 3 blocks high.  The three torches are probably overkill, but I wanted to make *sure* it was brightly lit :)