# How can I change my room to sleep safely?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Minecraft Nightmares (or, how to not get woken by mobs!)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17377/minecraft-nightmares-or-how-to-not-get-woken-by-mobs)

I have tried different combinations, I just shown two examples, but I am always wake up by monsters. How can I change my bedroom and sleep safely? I read the Minecraft [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed) but it is not clear why monster spawn in my case.

[image: Bed Position 1]

[image: Bed Position 2]

Answer (score 10):

Your room is pretty sparingly lit. It's possible one of the cubes in your room is at light level 6 or worse, meaning hostile mobs can and will spawn there.

Answer (score 1):

The basic rules are keep the bed 2 away from anywhere mobiles can get. I think for vertical distances the distance needs to be a little further away.. As it stands right now though in 1.5 there is a bug where beds are not always safe, even if they should be. Could be as simple as moving it to a different wall/location within the room above.. Also make sure there you are enclosed and well lit.. It is hard to tell but it would almost look like something could spawn where you are standing to take the second screen shot (The spawn range rules do not apply when sleeping it seems).

Answer (score 1):

The rules on the wiki don't take into account a possible bug in 1.5. The tests done in
[How do I construct a safe sleeping area in 1.5 version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20567/how-to-construct-a-safe-sleeping-area-in-1-5-version) suggest that the amount of flat space in front of and/or behind the door you use could be the culprit. Making sure there were 4 blocks both in front of and behind my doors did fix the problem in one of my bases, although there appear to be other circumstances that also work.