# Is it possible to skip past night in Minecraft single player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have an essentially brand-new Minecraft world.  Problem is, I haven't found anything I can use to make light yet, so as soon as night falls I get totally lost.  And I then have to sit still with the application open waiting for dawn so I can figure out where the Hell I am.  (I can't even alt-tab out, since that pauses the game.)

Is there any way to skip night so I can get back to trying to do something?

Comment: Wood and cobblestone are all you need to find before you can make light since charcoal was added to the game.

Comment: If you open the inventory pane, the game won't pause when you alt-tab out. The same goes for a lot of other panes in the game.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: even before that one could use the furnace itself as light source (so did I during my first few nights, powering it by wood and for the lack of better ideas melting cobblestone back to smooth stone...)

Comment: If you are not already attached to your new world, I suggest you to start another one. Probably you will have more luck in finding immediately some coal, or in any case you can perform the first tasks faster (pickaxe, furnace, charcoal, torches) before night falls.

Comment: open your inventory, that won't pause the game. It will "release" your mouse and then you can unfocus the window and do something else while your game is running

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, use a [bed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed). Build it like this (spoiler, hover above the grey box):

> Three times wool above three times wooden planks

Also, you can use a [Furnace](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Furnace) as temporary light source and as by-product obtain [charcoal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Charcoal):

> Get some wood, build a workbench and there a wooden pickaxe. Dig down until you reach stone, get 8, build a Furnace, use *unprocessed* wood as input and wooden planks as fuel. You obtain light plus charcoal for torches.

Comment: Of course, since the OP doesn't have a light source, the bed isn't going to do him much good…

Comment: @BenBlank: she could dig a hole into the floor with a small cave and seal the entrance with two blocks of wall in every direction

Comment: and see this [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20567/how-to-construct-a-safe-sleeping-area-in-1-5-version) for how to place the bed.

Comment: I would actually recommend using planks instead of logs as they burn just as long but you get 4 planks from every log.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: thank you, corrected. I haven't started a new game for a while so I didn't burn wood...

Comment: Go to sleep right after sunset and you wake up in the morning with hardly any monsters spawned.

Comment: @SF. Good point (I don't remember if that was also the case two years ago)

Answer (score 9):

This is how you make a bed:

[image: Bed Crafting!]

And this is how you make charcoal:

[image]

Comment: Note: Use the first charcoal you make to fuel the furnace to make more charcoal. (Charcoal burns as long as coal, eight times longer than the planks.)

Answer (score 2):

Well there are four most popular ways.

1. Make a bed... As Tobias suggested
2. Wait it out with the window open
3. Open your inventory ('e' or 'i'), then switch window. This stops the game from
   pausing.
4. Hacks :P

Comment: -1 he can't do any of these because he has no light source.

Comment: How do any of these require light? And the point is, do it during the day so you can skip the _next_ night.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a bed already you can sleep during the night with following construct.

```
      __
     xxx
     x
     x
gggggggggggg
```

Where g stands for ground, x is any material that can float (so no sand or gravel) and __ is your bed. When you build it like this you are save for to sleep in that bed (granted there isnt a ridge nearby where a skeleton could start shooting you.

Comment: Is this creeper-safe?

Comment: I have to say I've not tested it in 1.2 but it used to be. I can updated my post as soon as I know.

Comment: Of course to be fair, this question was asked before there was actually the danger of being awoken by mobs, back then one simply went to bed and next thing it was dawn...

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to commands, you can use `/gamerule doDaylightCycle false`.

Comment: creative solution :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a bed! Get one wood log and craft it into a plank (to make a crafting table), get another log and craft it too, and kill a couple of sheep for wool. Then use the crafting table like this:

   ```
   e e e - empty
   w w w - wool
   p p p - planks
   ```
2. If you have cheats enabled, use the `/time` code! To make it dawn, just hit `/` and type in `/time set 0` (the `/` will be there already) and you'll have skipped the night!