# mobs keeps spawning in my house

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Minecraft Nightmares (or, how to not get woken by mobs!)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17377/minecraft-nightmares-or-how-to-not-get-woken-by-mobs)
>   [How to construct a safe sleeping area in 1.5 version?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20567/how-to-construct-a-safe-sleeping-area-in-1-5-version)

I've built a rather large house with a high roof. I put up light everywhere to make it bright enough that a monster won't spawn in the house.

When I go to sleep in that house, monsters always spawn. So, I made a 4 square wide room, with only a bed, a door and 2 lights. Door closed, monsters still spawn inside the room!

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17377/minecraft-nightmares-or-how-to-not-get-woken-by-mobs - you probably need thicker walls.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug, although it isn't considered to be a bug (so I wouldn't bother reporting it). It can be triggered by creating two doors, but it is triggered by some other stuff as well (having door on a different level then the surrounding ground for example).

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20567/how-to-construct-a-safe-sleeping-area-in-1-5-version < Your bed will be too close to a 1 block thick wall I'd imagine.

Comment: Could also be the door assuming your bed isn't propped up against the wall.  Remember to insert doors from the outside of the house otherwise mobs can get in.

Comment: also, have you checked _underneath_ your bed? maybe there's only a 1 block thick floor...

Comment: I like the idea of having monsters under your bed. =)

Comment: this question made me lmao.